# How to select mapped data which are not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
tableA
Aid | Aname     |
1   | univer    |
2   | teaser    |

tableB
Bid | Bname |
66  |  ako  |
77  | fas   |
88  | yh    |
```

A value in `tableA` should be mapped with all the values in `tableB`

```
 tableC
 Aid | Bid  |
 1  | 66    |
 1  | 88    |
 2  | 66    |
 2  | 77    |
```

Now I want to select values from `tableA` mapped in `tableB` that are not in `tableC`.
For instance, I want find `Aid=1` and `Bid=77` since they are not found in the `tableC`, 
again, find `Aid=2` and `Bid=88` since they are not found in the `tableC`.

```
EXPECTED RESULTS
    Aid |   Bid |
    1   |   77  |
    2   |   88  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate all the permutations with a `cross join`, then you can use the `not exists` operator to filter out the permutations that already exist in `tablec`:

```
SELECT     aid, bid
FROM       tablea a
CROSS JOIN tableb b
WHERE      NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   tablec c
                       WHERE  c.aid = a.aid AND c.bid = b.bid)
```

**Sample Result:**

```
AID BID
1   77
2   88
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0399b5/1).